# Suppress "Push to remote repository?" prompt in TortoiseHg when pushing over SSH

Tags: mercurial, ssh, tortoisehg

In TortoiseHg, is it possible to suppress the confirm popup window that appears when pushing to an SSH repository?

It's the popup titled "Confirm Push to remote Repository" with a body text of "Push to remote repository ssh://server/repo?".

While I appreciate the warning, I'd like to disable it at least for some repos or some ssh paths.

Is it possible to disable this confirmation dialog and always allow the push?

[image]

Comment: It looks like someone submitted [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/190/push-always-wants-confirmation) to the tortoisehg devs, though it doesn't look like there's a fix or a workaround at the moment (and the last thread update was 4 days ago).

Comment: Thanks that looks like it, I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone has any solutions for now

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** This is a terrible answer and you shouldn't use it. But lacking a better option, here it is:

It is possible to write an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) script that instantly clicks through this box. This lacks finesse, since it ignores what repo you are trying to push to, but if you just want the box to go away, it mostly does the job.

```
While 1
    WinWaitActive("Confirm Push to remote Repository")
    Send("y")
Wend
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has now been resolved by the mercurial developers.
See https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/190/push-always-wants-confirmation

Answer (score 1):

In the Synchronize view, click the `Options` button, and check `Allow push of a new branch`

[image]